# Deploying snapshots always fails but deploying releases works fine

Tags: maven, deployment

when I run `mvn clean deloy` with a **snapshot-version** (eg `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`) to deploy a project to our enterprise nexus I always get the following build failure. When I run the same command with a release-version (eg `1.0.0`) the deployment to the release repository runs smoothly and the file is saved in the nexus:

```
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ META-POM ---
Downloading: http://urlofmynexus:port/nexus/content/repositories/nameofmygroup-snapshot/my/package/META-POM/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Uploading: http://urlofmynexus:port/nexus/content/repositories/nameofmygroup-snapshot/my/package/META-POM/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/META-POM-1.0.0-20160602.102009-1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.640 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-02T12:20:09+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project META-POM: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact my.package:META-POM:pom:1.0.0-20160602.102009-1 in nexus (http://urlofmynexus:port/nexus/content/repositories/nameofmygroup-snapshot) -> [Help 1]
```

This is the full log, I don't get any HTTP errors as I would get if my credentials would be wrong. I checked my proxy settings (as said in `[Help 1]` and some SO questions) and getting artifacts from the nexus (public and private repositories) or deploying releases works fine, only deploying snapshots always failing.

My questions are now:

1. Why can't I deploy snapshots to the nexus but releases? (main question)
2. Why is a timestamp added to the filename of the snapshot version when I have set `<uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>`? (secondary)

My settings.xml:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <username>nexususer</username>
    <password>nexuspw</password>
  </server>  
</servers>

<profiles>
 <profile>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>nexus</id>
         <url>http://urlofmynexus:port/nexus/content/groups/nameofmygroup-group</url>
         <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
         <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
       </repository>
    </repositories>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

My `distributionManagement` in project.pom:

```
<distributionManagement>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <name>Snapshots</name>
    <url>http://urlofmynexus:port/nexus/content/repositories/nameofmygroup-snapshot</url>
    <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
  </snapshotRepository>
  <repository>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <name>Releases</name>
    <url>http://urlofmynexus:port/nexus/content/repositories/nameofmygroup-releases</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

**edit** addional info:

- I already deleted my local repository several times
- This problem belongs to all my maven projects not a particual one. This seems logical as they all use the same nexus and settings.

Comment: Well, are you deploying `META-POM` also? Could you post your project structure? Is this a multi-module Maven project?

Comment: When something goes wrong with Maven, first thing i use to do is delete .M2 repo, then if it does not work, i'll start thinking at the issue itself... It worths always a try...

Comment: @Tunaki This is a log from a single single maven project called `META-POM` containing only one file called `META-POM.pom`. But also in other single and multimoduleprojects the error is the same. @ivoruJavaBoy already deleted my local repo several times. this had no influence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every thing looks ok. but i had the same error long time ago. I've simply misspelt the repository name.

so check the url again

```
http://urlofmynexus:port/nexus/content/repositories/nameofmygroup-snapshot
```

or

```
http://urlofmynexus:port/nexus/content/repositories/nameofmygroup-snapshots
```

with (s) at the end

Comment: Thats why I love code reviews *crash head against wall*